# could not coalesce error (error={ "code": -32002, "payload": { "method": "eth_requestAccounts",

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, hardhat, react

complete error-

```
could not coalesce error (error={ "code": -32002, "payload": { "method": "eth_requestAccounts", "params": [  ] } }, payload={ "method": "eth_requestAccounts", "params": [  ] }, code=UNKNOWN_ERROR, version=6.6.5)
```

I am trying to check if the user is connected to metamask and declaring a provider. But if the user is not connected to metamask then this error pops up. Here is the react code-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import BallotContract from "../ABI/Ballot.json"; // Import the Ballot contract ABI

const Ballots = () => {
  async function connectToContract() {
    window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
  }

  const contractAddress = "0xB30A0D72342eF7991DC14b31e9441c590063885a"; // Replace with the deployed contract address
  const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
  const signer = provider.getSigner();
  
  

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Ballot Interaction</h2>
      {typeof window.ethereum == "undefined" ? (
        <button onClick={connectToContract}>Connect to Contract</button>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <div>
            <h3>Create Issue</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Vote</h3>
            {/* Add code to select issue and vote */}
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Issues</h3>
            <ul></ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Ballots;
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey I think you are trying to access the provider of the current window which is not an ethereum object.Also you have to destructure the ethereum object from the window as the Metamask window is named as "ethereum" or in simple terms, Instead I would suggest you to put the following functionality inside the connectToContract function.

We will use the react hooks to store state variables to use them later.

```
const [provider, setProvider] = useState(null);
const [wallet, setWallet] = useState(null);

const connectToContract => async(){
       const { ethereum } = window;
       if (!ethereum) {
          alert("Get metamask!");
        }else{
           ethereum
             .request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })
             .then(async (accounts) => {
             setWallet(accounts[0]);
            setProvider(new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum));
            console.log(provider);
          });
       }
 }
```